# What was this weapon that Bakuto used?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017

In *Iron Fist*, Bakuto used an odd weapon to

> stab Danny.

It looked like this:

[image]

What’s more, there was a piece that broke off inside of Danny, which Claire later removed:

[image]

At first, it seemed as if there might be some link to the disruption of Danny’s chi, as his inability to use the Fist came immediately afterward (it certainly seemed a strange sort of weapon based purely on its shape), but no one brought up that possibility, and it seems that his inability to summon the Iron Fist was attributed to his emotional imbalance.

What weapon did Bakuto use, and did it have any special properties?

Comment: It looks like a modern arrowhead.

Comment: Could be a siangham...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a pocket stick a.k.a. [Kubotan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubotan) (a self-defense keychain weapon developed by Sōke Takayuki Kubota in the late 1960s) with sharpend head.

[image: kubotan]

Kubotan can be used e.g. to striking, stabbing, ***pressure point attacks*** and seizing.

Stick in Bakuto's hand could be just a pen too.

Comment: That does look similar. A strange choice of weapon.

Comment: It's almost an anagram. Bakuto, Kubota

Comment: @Adamant A [Kubota](https://www.kubotausa.com/) is something else entirely XD

Comment: @Adamant Kubota**n**

Comment: I know. That's why it's only *almost* an anagram. And obviously it wouldn't work in Japanese: クボタン。Although the Kubotan was invented by Kubota, whose name is an exact anagram.